# How to deal with FragmentPagerAdapter reusing Fragments?

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

So, I'm trying to use a ViewPager from Android's support v4 library, but there's some serious issues with how it (or FragmentPagerAdapter) deals with Fragments.  For instance, I subclassed FragmentPagerAdapter to do the following:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = null;
private ArrayList<Data> data = null;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<Data> data)
{
    super(fragmentManager);

    this.data = data;

    fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    for(Data datum : data)
    {
        MyDataFragment fragment = new MyDataFragment();
        fragment.setData(datum);
        fragments.add(fragment);
    }
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i)
{
    return fragments.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return fragments.size();
}
}
```

Now, I thought this would be sufficient, and that I could go on and implement `MyDataFragment` using the `onCreateView` method that Fragments typically implement.  But I ran into an interesting problem.  When I would navigate away from the Activity, and then back to it, the ViewPager would appear blank.  Somehow, it was reusing Fragments by calling findFragmentByTag, then simply not even calling `getItem`, etc.  What's worse, the Fragment would get no `onCreateView` event.  So I figured I could utilize the ViewPager's Fragment caching by moving my `onCreateView` code, which primarily grabs references to the various Views the fragment inflates, to `onAttach`.  The only problem is, that during `onAttach`, MyDataFragment's `getView` method always returns null.  All of the examples for Fragments online describe that `onCreateView` should have all of your view setup code.  Ok, fine.  But then, when I create a method like `MyDataFragment.setSomeField(String value)`, I need to use a reference to a `TextView`.  Since `onCreateView` doesn't always get called (like, when Fragments are magically recycled by FragmentPagerAdapter, for instance), it's better to grab that reference in `onAttach`.  However, during `onAttach`, the root view for the Fragment is still null (probably because `onCreateView` wasn't called in the first place)! No additional events happen after that (with the exception of `onActivityCreated`, which has nothing to do with the Fragment itself), so there's no place to do setup code.  How is this supposed to work?  Am I missing something important here, or was the Fragment system designed by a monkey?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the right use case for a FragmentPagerAdapter (it sounds more like something you'd want to do with a ListAdapter).

From the [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) docs:

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that represents each page as a Fragment
>   that is persistently kept in the fragment manager as long as the user
>   can return to the page.
>
> This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of
>   *typically more static fragments* to be paged through, such as a set of
>   tabs. The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in
>   memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible.
>   This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment
>   instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state. For larger sets
>   of pages, consider FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

I'd consider switching to the FragmentStatePagerAdapter or perhaps a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews).
If you want the createView to be called it will have to be recreated each time (destroy the old fragment and create new ones), but again I don't think that's quite what you want.